# Passing php-style array parameters from C# to a webservice

Tags: c#, soap

I have a problem with calling my partner's Soap webservice.
I have to write a client in C# to co-operate with this service. 
I am relatively new to webservices, sorry if my question is trivial, but i can't find the answer after hard hours of googleing.

So, the service (written in php) accepts parameters of key-value pairs. 
This structure (field names, types) is documented in a manual, but doesn't appears in wsdl (no type definitions in wsdl)

Part of WSDL:

```
    <message name="Authenticate">
    <part name="auth" type="xsd:anyType"/>  
    </message>
```

(For example, "auth" is an array type mentioned above, and this is an input parameter)

So these parameters appears in wsdl as "anyType".
When I generated the proxy classes (with Add Web reference option), i noticed that these parameters appears as "object" in auto-generated classes.

I tried to pass

- HashTable, Dictionary: these are not serializable.
- Array: not key-value pairs, two dimensional array not accepted, one dimensional is not enough (and not working, anyway).
- Custom class: i suppose that this will be the answer, but i have
  serialization problems.

My custom class is:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class AuthClass
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string AuthCode { get; set; }       
        }
```

So i created an instance of "Authclass", fill itt, and tried to pass to the service.

```
    Authclass a = new AuthClass(); 
    (...fill....)
    MyService s = new MyService(); //auto-generated proxy class
    s.Authenticate(a);  //auto-generated method
```

At runtime, i got a Serialization error message: the type HelloWsdl.AuthClass was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

I tried very much serialization attribute for the AuthClass, SoapInclude, XMLInclude, XmlRoot, etc, I am also tried cast to "object", using of object array, List, etc. but none of these solved the problem.

So my questions are

- How can i pass "php-style" array parameter to this web service? Which
  is the correct way?
- Is it possible to use the generated proxy classes    in this
  situation, or i have to choose another technique? In this    case,
  which technique is recommended?

Unfortunately I am not able to change the wsdl.